# turn a select option list in to regulair ul list

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have a script which allows to retrieve Google suggestions (XML) with Javascript and output in plain HTML:

```
<input  id='inp' /> <select  id='sug' />

<script type='text/javascript'>

function el(tid) {return document.getElementById(tid);}

function addScript(u){ 
   var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
     sc2=document.createElement('script'); sc2.src=u;    
   head.appendChild(sc2);
   setTimeout(function(){ head.removeChild(sc2); sc2=null;}, 20000)
 }//end addScript()


function suggest(data){ 
  var sel=el("sug").options; sel.length=0;
  data[1].map(function(a){return a[0];}).map(function(a,b){
  sel[b]=new Option(a);
 });
 sel.size=data[1].length;
}//end suggeest()


el("inp").onkeyup=function(){
  addScript("http://www.google.nl/complete/search?callback=suggest&q="+this.value);
}
```

As you can see the XML data is now a select option list. My question: How can I get this in a ul--->li HTML rather than the select option list.

Comment: loop through the options an create ul instead

Comment: I'm no JS expert but normally I can figure out many things just on my own. Except this on...I can barely read what is going on in this script, so doing something in a loop doesn't mean anything to me...

Comment: @Youss: Could you clarify what you want to happen? As I understand it,  there is XML that you want to convert into `ul` and `li` tags, but I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean. The XML is now converted into an option list, I would like a simple ul/li istead. So far I have tried in HTML: `<ul id='sug'>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>` And in JS: `function suggest(data){ 
  var sel=el("sug").list; sel.length=0;
  data[1].map(function(a){return a[0];}).map(function(a,b){
  sel[b]=new List(a);
 });
 sel.size=data[1].length;
}`  Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no standard DOM object to represent `ul / li` so your "OO" way isn't working... however, following seems to work in my FireFox browser: in the html body have a list like

```
<ul id='test'>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

and replace in JavaScript the `suggest` function with this one

```
function suggest(data){ 
  var sel=el("test"); sel.innerHTML='';
  data[1].map(function(a){return a[0];}).map(function(a,b){
  sel.innerHTML += '<li>'+a+'</li>';
 });
}
```

BTW add the list before the `select` element or write it like

```
<select  id='sug'></select>
<ul id='test'>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

(ie select is writen with proper end tag) otherwise the list won't show in the page

**EDIT:**
Version which seems to work in IE

```
function suggest(data){ 
  var sel=el("test"); sel.innerHTML='';
  for(x=0; x<data[1].length;x++){
     sel.innerHTML += '<li>'+data[1][x][0]+'</li>';
  }
}
```

Comment: I hope one day to have time to learn JS. But for now THANKS a lot:) It means a lot to me since this is the last thing I needed to complete my website.

Comment: He it doesn't work in IE8, its giving me an error at `data[1].map` etc. Do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: I tested your original code with IE6 and it won't work there either - it looks like array object in IE doesn't support `map` function? Perhaps rewriting the `suggest` function with manually looping the array will work? Sorry, I'm not JS/HTML guy myself so I'm not quite sure what the problem is...

Comment: See the answer, I updated it with anothe JS function which seems to work in IE6